# Sending Requests to Locally-hosted OpenSips Server using android

Tags: android, sip-server, opensips

I am really new to opensips and lately I was able to install the OpenSip server on my VirtualBox based VM ( Debian 10). Now I want to create an android application which enables SIP calling (Push to talk app) using that locally hosted OpenSip server.

I tried to understand the documentation on the OpenSips, but it is really tough for me. For now, to make sure that my OpenSip server is finely running and handling the SIP calls, can you suggest me a way to test it using an android programme?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try Linphone - it's an Android based SIP User Agent.